# How to set authorization headers with nodejs and express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, jwt, swig-template

I am setting up a site with nodejs, express, mongoose and swig template following this tutorial :
[Authenticate a Node.js API with JSON Web Tokens](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens)

In this tutorial the author uses Postman to set the token in the header.
I have googled for days to find out how I can set the jwt token in the header of my site, but it is not working for me.

Comment: It depends on how your site communicates with your Express server (jQuery, Angular, React, plain JS, etc).

Comment: Thanks for replying.
The site is in nodejs and express. I am using swig template for the html.

I am very new to nodejs. I have made the loginpage and I get my token. 
Now I want to store the token in the header of all sites in the folder /api/.
I tried to set the token in the header like this:
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('token', token;
  next();
});  
but it did not work.

Comment: Just to clarify, the client (the person using the API) should be sending the header with the token - not the server (as you are trying to do based on your question). In other words, your website should check the header, but clients should send it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Ashley. I understand what you mean. I cannot set the header from nodejs, because it haves to come from the client. That is why I could not find the solution. That means that I have to find a way to put the token into the swig-template. Is that correct?

Comment: @DanishWoman Put additional informations in your question! Edit your question!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want the client to include the token in it's request headers, you can use a cookie parser with express. (HTML5 Web Storage is another option). About Cookies:

Express can set the response headers to tell the client "add the token to a cookie".

Once the client sets the cookie with the token, the token will be in the client's request headers for each request. Let's get to baking with a little

```
npm install cookie-parser
```

Sprinkle on some

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
app.use(cookieParser())
```

Access and set a cookie:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var cookie = req.cookies.jwtToken;
  if (!cookie) {
    res.cookie('jwtToken', theJwtTokenValue, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
  } else {
    console.log('let's check that this is a valid cookie');
    // send cookie along to the validation functions...
  }
  next();
});
```

You will probably want to do these things with the cookies (or whatever method you go with in the end):

- set the cookie to hold the token when a user is authenticated.
- check the cookie header value before allowing access to protected
  routes.
- send back an unauthorized status if a user doesn't have their token
  when they are trying to access api routes that require a token.

Answer (score 1):

**May help someone in future...**

Storing token in `cookie` with `httpOnly:true` flag is pretty secure from XSS attack but it can be vulnerable to CSRF attack.

Adding custom `request headers` for all routes in `express` using a middleware might be a feasible solution like that:

```js
var token;

//asign 'accessToken' to 'token' in app.post('/login')
 token=accessToken;

app.all('*' , (req, res, next) => {

  if (!token) {
    console.log('token: undefined');
  } else {
    req.headers.authorization = 'Bearer ' + token; 
  }
  
  next();
});
```

this will add `authorization=Bearer <token>` header in each and every get request coming from browser. Now verify token in each secure route by adding this middleware:

let in `app.get('/dashboard')`

```js
const authenticateToken=(req, res, next)=>{

  var authHeader=req.headers['authorization'];
  var token=authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];
  
  if(token==null){
    return res.sendStatus(401);
  }
  
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN, (err, user)=>{
    if(err){
      return res.sendStatus(403);
    }
    
    req.user=user;
    next();
 })
}

//in app.get(...)
app.get('/dashboard', authenticateToken ,()=>{
      
      //stuff for authorized user
})
```

In case if  you defined `app.post('/login')` in another file then,

export `addHeader` middleware  as under:

```js
//var to access token outside app.post('/login') route
var token;

app.post('/login' , (req , res)=>{

    //authenticate the user
    
    //create token
    const accessToken=jwt.sign(user, secretKey);
    
    //assign 'accessToken' to  'token' var
    token=accessToken
    
    //redirect to secure route
    res.redirect('dashboard');
    
}

//middleware to add in your 'index.js' or 'app.js' file.
//export it only if you define app.post('/login') in another file

exports.addHeader = (req, res, next) => {

  if (!token) {
    console.log('token: undefined');
  } else {
    req.headers.authorization = 'Bearer ' + token; 
  }
  
  next();
}
```

In `index.js` or app.js

```js
//import file in which app.post('/login') is defined. let it is defined in controller/auth
const authController=require('./controller/auth');


//to add custom header in all routes
app.all('*', authController.addHeader);
```